# document.createElement not working with multi equal sign JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var a,b,c;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
    a = document.createElement('DIV');
    b = document.createElement('DIV');
    c = document.createElement('DIV');
}
```

**Question: Why example above works and example below not?**

```
var a,b,c;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
    a = b = c = document.createElement('DIV');
}
```

Comment: It should work, but in the second one, a, b, and c all point to the *same* element.

Comment: in the first example, you create three separate instances and assign them to separate variables. The second example creates one single instance and assigns it to all variables

Comment: What are you trying to do, that isn't achieved? As @catTS says, though, this is because you're pointing all variables at the same - single - created element.

Comment: If you want to create 3 different elements, you have to call `document.createElement()` 3 times.

Comment: because object instances are not simple values

Comment: In the event that your real problem is trying to find a shorthand means of creating multiple elements, then one way is to use "[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)" along with Array methods to act as an iterator, for example: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u65wdvkn/). But, obviously that isn't the answer to the question you've asked.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said, to create 3 divs you have to call "document.createElement()" 3 times.
In your 1st example you instantiate the variables at each loop.

As dube said in the second example the variables point to the same instance. Here is an example to do what you want.

```js
// array you use to iterate in your example
const refArray = [1, 2, 3]

// empty array you fill with the divs
let divArr = []

refArray.forEach(e => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  // push div in divArr
  divArr = [...divArr, div]
})

// destructuring array to get variable the variables that refer to your divs
const [a, b, c] = divArr
console.log("a:", a, "b: ", b, "c: ", c)
```